# Get CPU usage with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, cpu-usage

I have an AppleScript:

```
on run
    set pathName to "/Users/Alexander/Documents/GeekTool/DiskCapacityMeter"
    set usedSpace to (do shell script "df -hl | grep 'disk0s2' | awk '{sub(/%/, \"\");print $5}'") as integer

    set theNumber to (round (usedSpace / 5)) * 5

    do shell script ("cp " & pathName & "/img/" & theNumber & ".png " & pathName & "/temp.png")
end run
```

(downloaded from: [Here](http://cl.ly/ANko))

I wanna change this script to show my CPU usage instead of my disc capacity, and since i really don't know any AppleScript, i have no clue how to change it.

I just know i need to change this part:

```
(do shell script "df -hl | grep 'disk0s2' | awk '{sub(/%/, \"\");print $5}'")
```

to give me my CPU usage instead of my disc capacity.. if it's even possible to get my CPU usage this way?

edit*
There are 11 picures associated with this script (0-10.png) and a twelfth picture (temp.png) that changes to one of the first 11 depending on the number generated by the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how accurate this is, but the CPU usage at single points of time has a lot of variance:

```
ps axo %cpu | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
```

This would be even less accurate, because top itself uses a lot of CPU:

```
top -l1 -n0 | sed -En 's/^CPU usage: ([^%]*)% user, ([^%]*)%.*/\1+\2/p' | bc
```

Comment: `ps axo %cpu | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'` this kinda works..
but i get the error message: `error "Can not change \"67.1\" to type integer." number -1700 from "67.1" to integer`

Comment: do you know a way to get RAM usage?